# Почему дергается элемент при наведении?

Tags: html, css

Почему при наведении на элемент меню, он дергается?

```html
<nav class="menu">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Главная</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Брендинг</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Вэб-разработка</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Медиа-маркетинг</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Комплексное<br>продвижение</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Услуги</a>
              <li><a href="#">Порядок работы</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Этапы работы</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Портфолио</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
              <li ><a href="#">Конакты</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

```css
menu > ul  {
    display: flex !important;
}

.menu ul li {
    margin-right: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;

}

.menu ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}


.menu ul li:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s linear;
}

.menu ul li:hover .sub_menu{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.sub_menu {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.44);
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: visibility ease 0.3s, opacity ease 0.3s;
}

.sub_menu li {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    font-size: 15px;
}


.sub_menu li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Главная</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Брендинг</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Вэб-разработка</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Медиа-маркетинг</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Комплексное<br>продвижение</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Услуги</a>
              <li><a href="#">Порядок работы</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Этапы работы</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Портфолио</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
              <li ><a href="#">Конакты</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

весь код jsfiddle.net/92x7pqa3/

Сам сайт tempesv0.beget.tech

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в стиле на строке 281 применяется `font-weight: bold;` что увеличивает размер текста на несколько пикселей и приводит к тому что с остальным текстом за ним происходит смещение.
Если вы хотите предотвратить такое поведение лучше задать блокам с текстом фиксированную ширину, или убрать это свойство

---

Дергается

```
.menu ul li:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s linear !important;
}
```

---

Не дергается

```
.menu ul li:hover {
    /*font-weight: bold;*/
    transition: 0.3s linear !important;
}
```

---

для того что б исправить данную ситуацию советую добавить кастомный атрибут title что будет копировать текст вкладки и обращаться к title через css что зарезервирует для жирного текста размер внутри ::after, например было `<a href="#">Главная</a>` стало `<a href="#" title="Главная">Главная</a>`

```
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="Главная">Главная</a>
        <ul class="sub_menu">
          <li><a href="#">Брендинг</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Вэб-разработка</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Медиа-маркетинг</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Комплексное<br>продвижение</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" title="О нас">О нас</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Услуги">Услуги</a>
      <li><a href="#" title="Порядок работы">Порядок работы</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Этапы работы">Этапы работы</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Портфолио">Портфолио</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Новости">Новости</a></li>
      <li ><a href="#" title="Конакты">Конакты</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

советую убрать из кода данную строчку потому что она больше не нужна и transition ничего не делает

```
.menu ul li:hover {
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: 0.3s linear !important;
 }
```

после добавьте к стилям эти строки

```
.menu li a:hover {
  font-weight:bold;
}
.menu li a::after {
    display: block;
    content: attr(title);
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
}
```

и все должно заработать как ожидается

Comment: и какую ширину лучше задать?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в .menu ul li { witdh:140px; }

Comment: Вы увидите что эффект сдвига текста пропал потому что у элемента списка li появилась фиксированная ширина

Comment: а правильно ли будет для  nav задать max-width: 900px, например  и  width: 100% , для .menu ul justify-content:space-between, чтобы было правильнее? А то я задал для лишек отступ справа по 40 пикселей и не уверен, что это верно

Comment: вот есть элегантное решение данной проблемы <a href="https://overcoder.net/q/33556/%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8">overcoder.net<a>

Comment: Получилось, НО  у меня само меню съехало вверх и не работает transition       tempesv0.beget.tech

Comment: мне удалось пофиксить путем добавления height: 0; в .menu li a::after { ... } , можна задать значение height: 3px; будет еще ровнее

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы transition работал?

Comment: не получиться сделать что б transition bold'а работал единственное что хотелось бы улучшить добавить в .menu ul li {
    text-align: center;
}

Comment: есть еще замечание, если сделать ресайз окна браузера, стили никак не адаптируются, при разработке css желательно проверять результат сразу на разных размерах окна и желательно на разных устройствах